"Formula.Firewall: Query 'FY25_2YC' (step 'Source') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. " error
I am brand new to Power Query M and have next to no idea what I'm doing. I've been reading an article series on learning M but am obviously still not very experienced. I got the program working as individual steps but when I try to merge them all into one (so it's easy to copy/paste to new files and just change the file path) it gives the "Formula.Firewall: Query 'FY25_2YC' (step 'Source') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination." error.
= let

AllData = Folder.Files("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Trial Automation\Append Yearly Data\FY25_2YC"),

PartNumber = Table.SelectRows(AllData, each Text.StartsWith([Name], "12345")),

ExcelFileCheck = Table.SelectRows(PartNumber, each Text.StartsWith([Extension], ".xlsx")),

FilterHiddenFiles = Table.SelectRows(ExcelFileCheck, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),

CreateDataTables = Table.AddColumn(FilterHiddenFiles, "Transform File from FY25_2YC", each #"Transform File from FY25_2YC"([Content])),

IdentifySourceColumn = Table.RenameColumns(CreateDataTables, {"Name", "Source.Name"}),

CutFilePath = Table.TransformColumns(IdentifySourceColumn, {{"Folder Path", each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, "_2YC\"), type text}}),

GetMonthYear = Table.TransformColumns(CutFilePath, {{"Folder Path", each Text.Start(_, 6), type text}}),

AppendDay = Table.TransformColumns(GetMonthYear, {{"Folder Path", each "1-" & _, type text}}),

GetDate = Table.TransformColumnTypes(AppendDay,{{"Folder Path", type date}}),

SortDate = Table.Sort(GetDate,{{"Folder Path", Order.Ascending}}),

RemoveNonData = Table.SelectColumns(SortDate, {"Source.Name", "Transform File from FY25_2YC"}),

ExpandData = Table.ExpandTableColumn(RemoveNonData, "Transform File from FY25_2YC", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File from FY25_2YC"(#"Sample File"))),

SetDataTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(ExpandData,{{"Date", type date}, {"Time", type time}, {"Collector ID", Int64.Type}, {"OPERATOR", type text}, {"MODEL", type text}, {"EVENT", type text}, [redacted for security but you get the idea]

Result = Table.RemoveColumns(SetDataTypes,{"Source.Name"})

in

Result

For some context, CutFilePath to GetDate is all turning the "mon-yr" in the file name into an actual date I can sort.
